# How to run crop intent like Android "nougat" phone app?

Tags: android

I know that com.android.camera.action.CROP is not supported, but how can I lunch crop intent from photos app as exist in the latest Android "nougat" phone app when creating new contact and set an image for it?

Comment: Android is an operating system. It does not have a "photos app". *Devices* may have a "photos app". That app may vary from device to device, based upon the manufacturer. None have to support third-party apps invoking them for cropping purposes. Use [an image-cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created), please.